# How to pass multidimensional array in collection view inside the tableview cell?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

I have multidimensional array for example like following, how can I pass the array of my collection view on / of a table views / viewed cel ?

```
let array = [["abc " , " bce "] , ["a "] , ["abc " , " abce " , " a "] , []]
```

I want first array object of first cell, second array object of second cell and continuous.

Comment: I think you need sections and cells inside of sections each array as a section and each value as a cell

Comment: If you want to convert that to simple array then use  `let arr =  array.flatMap{$0}` or you can use section tableview

Answer (score 2):

You can implement like this way

```
extension YourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return array[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath)
        let string = array[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedString = array[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
    }

}
```